# ReSharper: setting C# language level for Solution

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2015, c#-5.0, c#-6.0, resharper-9.0

Further to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1374849/214747) question, I have lots of projects inside a solution and I dont want to create a `dotsettings` file for each project. Can anyone help me set the C# Language Level on a solution level.

This is relevant for me as I downloaded [VS2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs) today and ReSharper is offering me useful refactor suggestions based on targeting C# 6 and my projects are using C#5.

Comment: Have you tried setting the language version for the project in Visual Studio? Go to project properties -> Build -> Advanced... -> Language Version

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I added below settings in `.sln.DotSettings`

```
<s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeInspection/CSharpLanguageProject/LanguageLevel/@EntryValue">CSharp50</s:String>
```

This line was added to `.csproj.DotSettings` when I tried to disable c#6 for a particular project. After adding this line in `.sln.DotSettings` resharper is reporting an error whenever I am trying to use c# 6.0 feature.

Comment: this worked great thanks. problem resolved. please refer to this gist for my final dotsetting file. https://gist.github.com/chris-brown/b47ea61ef2c93af50bee

Comment: Can be applied at project level, solution level, or user level, which is at `%APPDATA%\JetBrains\Shared\vAny\GlobalSettingsStorage.DotSet‌​tings`

Comment: It's also possible to set for each project in solution the C# language version via `Project Properties > Build tab > Advanced...` and ReSharper will detect it by it's own and avoids to suggest greater than configure language features. It is mor eto configure but you will ensure that nobody without ReSharper can use language version features above your defined one.

Answer (score 9):

According to Jetbrains documentation about [C# default version](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/ReSharper_by_Language__CSharp.html), you can specify the target C# version explicitly by selecting the project in the Solution Explorer and using the C# Language Level property in the Visual Studio's Properties window.

Comment: Please post relevant section here.

Comment: from the link ... "you can specify the target C# version explicitly by selecting the project in the Solution Explorer and using the C# Language Level property in the Visual Studio's Properties window (choose View | Properties Window in the menu). " - it is not the project's properties as in right-click the project, properties.